# What are the factors that affect delay/latency between base stations?

Tags: communication, wireless, network, latency

I am modelling a 5G network, with the uplink and downlink being decoupled and treated as separate networks.

I am exploring the integration of fog computing and how latency varies between different base stations (eNBs) and mobiles (UEs).

For example for channel gain, this is affected by fading, path loss etc. but what affects the latency?

Comment: Not really a valid EE question I reckon.

Comment: @Andyaka Wireless communications lie within electrical engineering

Comment: It doesn't make it a valid question on this site. [Read this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and note that questions about consumer electronics are off-topic.

Comment: @Andyaka I don't see how this is a 'consumer electronic' question, as it is about modeling a 5G network, which is neither a product nor something consumers do.

Comment: The point is that consumer electronics are usually inaccessible in terms of what the real electronic design is AND, likewise, the 5G network (and the mobiles you mention) are the same. This means nobody can make any engineering judgements on this except an absolute specialist in the field and then this question (and any answers) becomes quickly invalid over time. Basically, no circuit (or code) to analyse means nothing doing.

Comment: @Andyaka I interpreted this question more as a high level 'what-part-of-the-5G-standard-causes-this' and not about a specific phone. But I don't want us to get into an argument over this in the comment sections, I think we best wait untill the OP can provide more information about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoiding the debate in the comments section I'll try and answer your question as "but what effects latency?"

With wireless communications most latency would be with the modulation and demodulation process as the signal needs to be processed. have a read off this it should help
 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/326892443_Low-latency_Networking_Where_Latency_Lurks_and_How_to_Tame_It